# Error running python runserver --nothreading -noreload

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

```
/home/saumen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py:316: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if subcommand == 'runserver' and '--noreload' not in self.argv:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/saumen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/saumen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/saumen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/saumen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/saumen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/saumen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 86, in handle
    'or address:port pair.' % options['addrport'])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am getting the error when I run python runserver --nothreading -noreload.what Can I do? I have installed mysqlclient and necessary python libraries.

Comment: Please show ```line number 22``` from ```manage.py``` file

Comment: Errors says its all `options['addrport']` contains some non ascii character.

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav line 22: execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

Comment: @SaumenRoy Please show ```line number 86``` from ```runserver.py``` file

Comment: What version of Django are you running? If it is 2.0 or greater... it won't work, because you're using Python 2.7, which will no longer be supported in 7 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First edit your answer and put code on line 86...
and error is happening because of  UnicodeDecodeError:

This might work for you:(note: your_string is what you want to decode)

```
your_String.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
```

for more specific to your problem:

```
str(options['addrport']).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
```